# What is the best way to pass data to a payment gateway for processing using php with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I need to create a custom form (Step 1, Step 2, etc) And at the end of the form, pass details securely** (ie. customer first name, last name, product package chosen($, $$, $$$), etc ) to a payment gateway for processing.

1. Is there a plugin that does this? If so, which one and where could i find the appropiate api details to get started?
2. Or do i have to create a custom payment gateway solution? If so, then what is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: have you tried researching? if so, what did you find? other things you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use WP-eCommerce. That has quite a lot of built in payment gateways. The only problem there would be the custom form. Maybe you could create the custom form and post the results to the correct location to add something to the WP-eC cart?

Comment: Will try this. Thanks for your effor Fuzz!

Comment: Not a problem. I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but hopefully it might be a step in the right direction.